# How to Apply the Imageview event on ImageResource

Tags: android, imageview

i want that when i write something in edittext (title)or in textinputedittext(discription )
The resource of imageview (save) change to other image
How can i write code for this ?
[image]

I wrote this code but it didn't  worked

If ( textinputedittext_discription .getText().length()>0  ||  edittext_title.getText().length()>0){
Imageview_save.setImageResource(R.darawable.ic_newsave);
}

Comment: I think you need a listener in the editText to detect if the user write something or not, so you can try TextWatcher: yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWathcer { }), override the three methos and use onTextChanged()

Comment: If worked, please rate the answer to help the community. Thanks!